# ¿Cómo hago que devuelva un string?

Tags: javascript, json

estoy tratando de hacer una variable con una función pero no consigo que la función me devuelva un string, el código que tengo es este.

```
var islog = window.onload=function (){
  if(localStorage.getItem("islog")!=null){
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("islog"));}
  return  false
  };
```

Comment: No devuelve un string porque tu estás devolviendo `false` que es booleano, cambia `return false` por `return "un string"` (u otra variable que contenga lo que tu quieres retornar, siempre que sea un string) y te retornará un string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me da a mi que tu lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var islog = return (localStorage.islog ? JSON.parse(localStorage.islog) : false;)
}
```

Para en un futuro usarlo como:

```
if (islog) {
   alert("Está loggeado en el sistema");
} else {
  alert("Por favor ingrese para continuar");
}
```

Lo que me lleva a pensar que andas jugueteando con javascript para ir entendiéndolo.

Entonces creo que merece la pena comentarte que la fase de loggin se debe realizar en el back-end/servidor. De esta forma nadie podrá acceder al usuario y contraseña mirando el código de la aplicación.

Lo correcto en mi opinión es hacer un input text, un input password y un button type button para poder enviar una petición HTTP con el método POST a un servidor (Usando xhr o fetch). Por ejemplo a un Apache con PHP.

En el servidor compruebas si el login es correcto y en caso de serlo mandas una web o una cookie de session. Y en caso de no serlo mandas un mensaje de error.

Firebase también es interesante si no quieres manejar un servidor. Tienen videos muy buenos.

Comment: Hola @String muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Corrige, estas devolviendo false.

```
var islog = window.onload=function (){
  if(localStorage.getItem("islog")!=null){
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("islog"));
 }
};
```

Recuerda que estas guardando la declaracion de la funcion, lo que significa que ahora debes usarlo asi:

```
alert(islog());
```